# Understanding RE output of a simple C++ program

Tags: assembly, c++

I am trying to learn RE and I decided to explore this field by reverse engineering a simple C++ program, which I post here:

**SIMPLE C++ PROGRAM**

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int value;
    std::cout << "Hello Word";
    std::cin >> value;

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled it using MSVC compiler (VS 2017, x86 build). I wanted to understand the assembly language behind it.

For RE I use Ghidra tool. I am currently focused only on understanding the assembly part, rather than Decompiled part, because that one makes less sense to me at the moment, but mayber if I understand the Assembly part, I would be able to decode the decompiled output.

**ASSEMBLY OUTPUT:**

```
                     //
                     // .text 
                     // ram: 00401000-00401f9a
                     //
                     **************************************************************
                     *                          FUNCTION                          *
                     **************************************************************
                     int __cdecl main(void)
     int               EAX:4          <RETURN>
     int               EAX:4          value                                   XREF[1]:     00401032(W)  
     char *            Stack[-0x8]:4  hello_string                            XREF[2]:     0040100d(W), 
                                                                                           0040102b(R)  
     undefined1        Stack[-0xc]:1  local_c                                 XREF[1]:     00401021(*)  
                     .text$mn                                        XREF[3]:     0040012c(*), 00400204(*), 
                     main                                                         __scrt_common_main_seh:00401500(
00401000 55              PUSH       EBP
00401001 8b ec           MOV        EBP,ESP
00401003 83 ec 08        SUB        ESP,0x8
00401006 a1 04 30        MOV        EAX,[___security_cookie]                         = BB40E64Eh
         40 00
0040100b 33 c5           XOR        EAX,EBP
0040100d 89 45 fc        MOV        dword ptr [EBP + hello_string],EAX
00401010 8b 0d 54        MOV        ECX,dword ptr [->MSVCP140.DLL::std::cout]        = 000027ec
         20 40 00
00401016 e8 25 00        CALL       std::operator<<<struct_std::char_traits<char>_>  basic_ostream<char,struct_std::c
         00 00
0040101b 8b 0d 4c        MOV        ECX,dword ptr [->MSVCP140.DLL::std::cin]         = 0000284a
         20 40 00
00401021 8d 45 f8        LEA        EAX=>local_c,[EBP + -0x8]
00401024 50              PUSH       EAX
00401025 ff 15 34        CALL       dword ptr [->MSVCP140.DLL::std::basic_istream<
         20 40 00
0040102b 8b 4d fc        MOV        ECX,dword ptr [EBP + hello_string]
0040102e 33 c0           XOR        EAX,EAX
00401030 33 cd           XOR        ECX,EBP
00401032 e8 fe 02        CALL       @__security_check_cookie@4                       undefined @__security_check_cook
         00 00
00401037 8b e5           MOV        ESP,EBP
00401039 5d              POP        EBP
0040103a c3              RET
```

I am trying to follow the assembly code line by line. I understand some basics of the registers mentioned there and stack allocation, but I get lost during the `dword ptr MOV` instructions and then that `CALL` instruction.

if anyone could please elaborate to me what is happening actually there, I will start to better understand how to approach assembly code when doing RE tasks.

Comment: what command line did you pass to msvc cl.exe ? do you use a project ?  and built it with default ? or did you copy paste correctly there appears to be some thing amiss in the paste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two lines are function prologue and you will see them at the beginning of almost every function:

```
PUSH       EBP
MOV        EBP,ESP
```

They basically save the current `EBP` value and then store current `ESP` into `EBP`, so that the local variables and function arguments can be accessed via `EBP` (`ESP` has to change when you allocate the memory on the stack). In this case, function arguments passed via the stack will be accessed by `[RBP + offset]` while local variables by `[RBP - offset]`.

The next line is about memory allocation - function reserves `8` bytes for its own use:

```
SUB        ESP,0x8
```

In the next three lines, there is a protection against [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow).

```
MOV        EAX,[___security_cookie]
XOR        EAX,EBP
MOV        dword ptr [EBP + hello_string],EAX
```

Here `[EBP + hello_string]` contains a random value when [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) is turned on. The value stored there will likely be different during each program execution and that will make it hard for potential attacker to predict it - if he fails to, it will be detected later on in the line with `CALL @__security_check_cookie@4`.

It's important to note here, that the local variable (offset) that you named `hello_string` doesn't have anything in common with the "Hello Word" string - it's there only for preventing exploits.

Now, let's skip the next two lines for a moment - we'll come back to them later on.

So, now we have:

```
MOV        ECX,dword ptr [->MSVCP140.DLL::std::cin]
LEA        EAX=>local_c,[EBP + -0x8]
PUSH       EAX
CALL       dword ptr [->MSVCP140.DLL::std::basic_istream<
```

The first line passes the global `cin` object as a first parameter to the operator function. It's because it is the `__thiscall` convention which ([source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/thiscall?view=vs-2019))

> is the default calling convention used by C++ member functions that do not use variable arguments [...] with the **this** pointer being passed via register ECX, and not on the stack, on the x86 architecture.

Then, the pointer to the local variable `value` is passed and the `>>` operator member function of `cin` is being called.

The remaining lines:

```
MOV        ECX,dword ptr [EBP + hello_string]
XOR        EAX,EAX
XOR        ECX,EBP
CALL       @__security_check_cookie@4       
MOV        ESP,EBP
POP        EBP
```

set `EAX` (which will contain function return value) to `0`, then checks whether a buffer overflow occured and then restores the `ESP` value before allocating space for local variables and the `EBP` value from the beginning of the function (`EBP` has to be preserved, otherwise other functions could change it and then `ESP` would be changed to the wrong value).

There are two lines not analysed yet:

```
MOV        ECX,dword ptr [->MSVCP140.DLL::std::cout]
CALL       std::operator<<<struct_std::char_tra
```

They are problematic for two reasons:

1. The second argument to the `<<` is not being passed (though it's required).
2. As you may notice, contrary to the `cin` case, non-member function is being called, so the first argument should have been passed via stack and not as in the `__thiscall` convention:

   1. `>>` for (`cin`, `int`) is member function: [source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt)
   2. `<<` for (`cout`, `const char*`) is non-member function: [source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt).

As you can see in the disassembly posted by @blabb, these two arguments are indeed passed via the stack, while in yours - only one is passed and not by the stack.

So, it seems that this code doesn't work - it doesn't even reference the string you want to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this case, `hello_string` is, in fact, referring to the security cookie storage location.

in `0040100d` the stack cookie is saved to the stack. You can [Read more here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16241/what-could-be-the-purpose-of-xoring-esp-with-a-global-variable-stack-canary-pr)

Answer (score 0):

It looks there's something wrong with your code, it looks like there's no parameter for the operator<<.

Can you try to add either a '\n' on the string or use `<< std::endl` and see if the generated code is different?

Answer (score 0):

By default __security_cookie **[is not enabled for all functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/strict-gs-check?view=vs-2019)**
msvc vs 2017 does not insert __security_check for the code in question
either with optimizations or without optimizations

i had to force it with #pragma

source , commandline for compiling and disassembly as below

source

```
:/>dir /b si*
simp.cpp

:/>type simp.cpp
#include <iostream>
#pragma strict_gs_check(on) <<< had to force stricter security checks
int main() {
    int value;
    std::cout << "Hello Word";
    std::cin >> value;
    return 0;
}
```

\compiled and linked with

```
:/>cl /Zi /W4 /analyze /Od /GS /EHsc simp.cpp /link /release
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27025.1 for x86
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

simp.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.16.27025.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:simp.exe
/debug
/release
simp.obj

:/>simp.exe
Hello Word

p
```

disassembly

```
:/>cdb -c "uf simp!main;q" simp.exe | awk "/Reading/,/quit/"
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'uf simp!main;q'
simp!main:
013a1190 55              push    ebp
013a1191 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
013a1193 83ec08          sub     esp,8
013a1196 a16c904201      mov     eax,dword ptr [simp!__security_cookie (0142906c)]
013a119b 33c5            xor     eax,ebp
013a119d 8945fc          mov     dword ptr [ebp-4],eax
013a11a0 68f0214101      push    offset simp!__xt_z+0x10 (014121f0)
013a11a5 6830ab4201      push    offset simp!std::cout (0142ab30)
013a11aa e861010000      call    simp!std::operator<<<std::char_traits<char> > (013a1310)
013a11af 83c408          add     esp,8
013a11b2 8d45f8          lea     eax,[ebp-8]
013a11b5 50              push    eax
013a11b6 b9b8aa4201      mov     ecx,offset simp!std::cin (0142aab8)
013a11bb e8b0280000      call    simp!std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> >::operator>> (013a3a70)
013a11c0 33c0            xor     eax,eax
013a11c2 8b4dfc          mov     ecx,dword ptr [ebp-4]
013a11c5 33cd            xor     ecx,ebp
013a11c7 e8e63a0200      call    simp!__security_check_cookie (013c4cb2)
013a11cc 8be5            mov     esp,ebp
013a11ce 5d              pop     ebp
013a11cf c3              ret
quit:
```